# import statistics in visual studio code using Python 3.8 cannot find median

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can import statistics with Visual Studio Code Python 3.8.0. I can even see the intellisense options for median, median_low, etc.

```
import statistics as st

numbers  = [0, -6, 10, 5, 8, 2, -12, 11, -2]

print(numbers)

numbers.sort()

print(numbers)

#[-12, -6, -2, 0, 2, 5, 8, 10, 11]
print("\nmedian of the numbers")
print(st.median(numbers))
```

However when I go to execute the code I get the following in Visual Studio Code. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
[0, -6, 10, 5, 8, 2, -12, 11, -2]
[-12, -6, -2, 0, 2, 5, 8, 10, 11]

median of the numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/ProgrammingSource/Python/PracticeVarious/pracNumbers.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(st.median(numbers))
AttributeError: module 'statistics' has no attribute 'median'
```

I did take my code and used it in Anaconda/Spyder and Anaconda/Jupyter it actually worked. Jupyter does not have Intellisense and Spyder sometimes does not show up the different options. Visual Code lets me see my different options.

I am not trying to make this a discussion of which Python IDE to use. just trying to figure out what I am typing wrong in Visual Studio Code.

I did find a similar question, but the person did not specify which Python they had.
mine is 3.8.0 below:

```
PS D:\ProgrammingSource\Python\PracticeVarious> python
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might already have a file named statistics.py in the current working directory. Check whether it exists in this directory -

> D:\ProgrammingSource\Python\PracticeVarious

It is showing error because instead of importing the default statistics module it is importing statistics.py. To solve this issue just rename the file named statistics.py.

Comment: That was it!  I could not even see that and when I did it in the other ones I did not notice I was not in the same directory! Good catch!!